# Error adding RoboGuice as dependency

Tags: android, android-studio, gradle, roboguice

I'm trying to install RoboGuice as a dependency in my Android Studio project. As soon as I attempt to run the project (even before I've added any new code), I crash with this output:

Information:Gradle tasks [:app:assembleDebug]
:app:preBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:preDebugBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:checkDebugManifest
:app:preReleaseBuild UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportAppcompatV72300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComAndroidSupportSupportV42300Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareComMcxiaokeVolleyLibraryAar100Library UP-TO-DATE
:app:prepareDebugDependencies
:app:compileDebugAidl UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugRenderscript UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugBuildConfig UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugAssets UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResValues UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:mergeDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugManifest UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugResources UP-TO-DATE
:app:generateDebugSources UP-TO-DATE
:app:processDebugJavaRes UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugJava
Note: Some input files use or override a deprecated API.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:deprecation for details.
:app:compileDebugNdk UP-TO-DATE
:app:compileDebugSources
:app:preDexDebug
:app:dexDebug
UNEXPECTED TOP-LEVEL EXCEPTION:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Ljavax/inject/Provider;
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.readSortableTypes(DexMerger.java:596)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.getSortedTypes(DexMerger.java:554)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeClassDefs(DexMerger.java:535)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.mergeDexes(DexMerger.java:171)
    at com.android.dx.merge.DexMerger.merge(DexMerger.java:189)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.mergeLibraryDexBuffers(Main.java:454)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.runMonoDex(Main.java:303)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.run(Main.java:246)
    at com.android.dx.command.dexer.Main.main(Main.java:215)
    at com.android.dx.command.Main.main(Main.java:106)
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:dexDebug'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command '/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/jdk1.7.0_21.jdk/Contents/Home/bin/java'' finished with non-zero exit value 2
>   Information:BUILD FAILED
>   Information:Total time: 10.274 secs
>   Information:1 error
>   Information:0 warnings
>   Information:See complete output in console

Here are my gradle files:

build.gradle (Module)
    apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

```
android {
    compileSdkVersion 23
    buildToolsVersion "21.1.2"

    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.mysite.myapp"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 23
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    compile fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.0'
    compile 'com.google.code.gson:gson:2.3.1'
    compile 'com.mcxiaoke.volley:library-aar:1.0.0'
    compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'
    compile 'org.roboguice:roboguice:3.+'
}
```

build.gradle (project)

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:1.2.3'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}
```

I'm totally perplexed. Can anyone see what I am doing wrong? Thanks.

Comment: By any chance, have you put any of the libraries specified in `dependencies` in libs folder also? please post the screenshot of contents of your libs folder if possible.

Comment: Why did you add compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1' to your dependencies? Should imho not be needed when using gradle, Roboguice should resolve that dependency on it'ts own.

Comment: @Ascorbin - I've been playing with various attempts at dependency injection all day. That was left over from an earlier approach, but appears to be the source of the duplication. If you propose it as an answer, I'll accept it. Thanks!

Comment: @Randall I did, thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Roboguice will bring it's 'own' `javax.inject` as a dependency, so when you're declaring  `compile 'javax.inject:javax.inject:1'` there's 2 of them resulting in

> Multiple dex files define Ljavax/inject/Provider

Just remove the `javax.inject` dependency.